# run gnu-screen/tmux/byobu from client

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

I need to understand a fundamental concept about terminal multiplexers yet I can't seem to find the answer.

As I understand these programs need to be installed on server but not necessarily on clients. It's not a problem with gnu-screen as it is already installed on most systems but it's not the case for tmux and byobu. The problem is that I don't have permission to install software on the server. Is there a way I can run byobu from my client to show statistics about the server I connect?

Also what exactly is the effect of 'byobu-enable' option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a misunderstanding here.  When you connect to the server and run a command (byobu in this case), you are running the command on the server.  Statistics reported are for the server.  It's possible to open a byobu session on your own desktop of course, but if you're ssh'd into a machine, you're very likely to be executing commands on that machine.

byobu-enable sets byobu to launch automatically when you open a terminal.  I don't do this since you can have confusion if you have byobu running locally *and* on the remote end you have connected to, which causes problems when you try to interact with byobu itself.

Comment: I had long forgotten about this question. I had learned much about terminal multiplexers by now. I guess it's not possible to use byobu without first installing it to the server, at least it's not trivial..

Comment: I figured the answer was probably no longer needed, but thought I'd put it out there to be indexed and stored for some future need.